# Access to sftp through FortiClient on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, vpn, forticlient

I have a NodeJS backend, in some function I need to read a remote file on an external sftp server, but I need to access through a FortiClient VPN, there's no way to access that sftp without VPN.

Is there a way to connect to sftp with that VPN client?

I've read about clients for OpenVPN like https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-vpn-client but I need it for FortiClient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function is running in a cloud service (AWS, GCP, Azure, etc), you can access the VPN through a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) which can be used by the function to connect to; although if your service is running in a private server/host, you can deploy a VPN connection from the console using Forticlient in your server, which [is available for several distributions](https://www.forticlient.com/downloads).

Here are some links that could be useful:

- [Fortigate Cookbook GCP VPC](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.2.0/gcp-cookbook/396681/creating-vpc-networks)
- [Fortigate Cookbook AWS VPC](https://docs.fortinet.com/vm/aws/fortigate/6.2/aws-cookbook/6.2.0/506140/connecting-a-local-fortigate-to-an-aws-vpc-vpn)
- [Fortigate Cookbook Azure VPN](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.2.0/azure-cookbook/989216/connecting-a-local-fortigate-to-an-azure-vnet-vpn)